# Generic Array List

Tags: java, arrays, generics, get, bluej

I need to create an array list using generics. My add method seems to work sometimes, however my get method appears to have a good amount of problems and i don't receive a compile error. However when i try to get an object from the Array list using my get method it throws a java out of bounds exception. here i what i have so far, and i am using BlueJ. Also, the instructions were to set the initial "illusion" length to zero.

```
public class AL <X> {
    private X[]data;
    private int count;

    public  AL() {
        count = 0;
        data = (X[]) new Object[0];
    }

    public void add (X v) {
        if (data.length != count) {
            data[count] = v;
            count++;
        } else {
            X [] newdata = (X[]) new Object[data.length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                newdata[i] = data [i];
            }
            count++;
            data = newdata;
        }
    }

    public X get(int index) {
        if (index >= count || index < 0) {
            throw new ICantEven();
        } else {
            return data[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `add` method doesn't work, since the initial backing array you are using has a 0 length, which remains 0 even when you try to double it (since 0*2==0).

You also forgot to actually add the new element when you resize the backing array. If you hadn't forgot that, you'd get the exception in `add`.

First of all, change the initial size of the array created by your constructor to be positive :

```
data = (X[]) new Object[10];
```

Then add

```
data[count] = v;
```

to the else clause of your `add` method (just before `count++;`).

Your add method can be further simplified :

```
public  AL()
{
    count = 0;
    data = (X[]) new Object[10];
}

public void add (X v)
{
    // resize backing array if necessary
    if (data.length == count)
    {
        X [] newdata = (X[]) new Object[data.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length;i++ )
        {
            newdata[i] = data [i];
        }
        data = newdata;
    }
    // add new element
    data[count] = v;
    count++;
}
```